# Why do notebooks sometimes need a battery reset?

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

I just recently had to reset the battery [disconnect and replace the battery] of my Acer Swift 1 since it wouldn't turn on. To my surprise they actually built in a little hole in the back of the device that enables resetting it with a paperclip.

This made wonder however. I've had this issue with almost every notebook i've owned so far. Can someone explain to me what causes it?

Thanks

Comment: What is a "_battery reset_"? Can you include a photo of the little hole, or a link to the product manual that outlines the procedure?

Comment: im talking about removing the battery and putting in in again.

Comment: Before removing the battery, did you try holding the power button for ~5 seconds and then trying to power on again?

Comment: Yes I did, didnt work. Im not asking how to fix it, im asking why it happens.

Comment: There could be many reasons... If pressing and holding worked, then it might indicate a lockup at the OS level... as that didn't work, you may have over discharged it?? I can't say I've ever knowingly experienced this - certainly not on "_almost every notebook I've owned_"...